# Loop Through Entire Directory php

Tags: php

I can loop through a directory and one subfolder like this

```
$directoryArray = scandir('../portalFolders/');
        foreach($directoryArray as $directory){
            $listString .='
                <li class="closed"><span class="folder">'.$directory.'</span>';
                $subDirectoryArray = scandir('../portalFolders/'.$directory);
                $howManyFolders = $subDirectoryArray -> count();
                if($howManyFolders > 0){
                    $listString .= '<ul>';
                        foreach($subDirectoryArray as $subDirectory){
                            $listString .=  '<li class="closed"><span class="folder">'.$subDirectory.'</span><li>';
                        }
                    $listString .= '</ul>'; 
                }
                else{
                    $listString .= '</li>';
                }       
        }
```

How Can I make it search/loop through ALL of the child directories of the sub directories without me nesting another `foreach()`? This way, I can add as many folders/subfolders as I want via FTP and not have to make the nest deeper in the code.

Comment: Make a recursive function.

Comment: So put this in a function and call the function within itself?

Comment: Look up the [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php).

Comment: Just a note: `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` is pretty slow when you have many files. `scandir` / `readdir` are better options...

Comment: Hows about this? `function loopThrough(){
   $directoryArray = scandir('../portalFolders/');
   foreach($directoryArray as $directory){
    $listString .='
     <li class="closed"><span class="folder">'.$directory.'</span>';
     $subDirectoryArray = scandir('../portalFolders/'.$directory);
     $howManyFolders = $subDirectoryArray -> count();
     if($howManyFolders > 0){
      $listString .= '<ul>';
       loopThrough();
      $listString .= '</ul>'; 
     }
     else{
      $listString .= '</li>';
     }  
   }
  }`

Comment: Comments don't really structure code well lol. sorry. I'm going to try the recursive. I have some reading to do on RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have hinted at, you'll likely use some form of recursion to do this. But here's an example of how you might do it without the use of RecursiveDirectoryIterator:

```
function listDirectories($dir) {
    echo "<ul><li>$dir";
    foreach (glob("$dir/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $d) {
        listDirectories($d);
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
listDirectories('.');
```